# how to use x-editable-rails in the 'show' view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i installed a x-editable-rails demo, that is possíble to find here:

https://github.com/diogowernik/x_editable_rails_demo

It works fine in the index view (site.com/articles) it is possible to edit title and description

but i would like also to have it active in the show view (Ex: site.com/articles/1, articles/2, etc..)

in the index view, that is the code:

```
<td><%= editable article, :title %></td>
<td><%= editable article, :content, type: "textarea" %></td>
```

in the show view, that is the code:

```
<h3>  <%= @article.title %> </h3>
<p>  <%= @article.content %> </p>
```

I tryed without success some thing like that:

```
<h3>  <%= editable article, @article.title %> </h3>
<p>  <%= editable article, @article.content %> </p>
```

i get this error

NameError in Articles#show

thank a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After while i found the answer:

in the show view that is the sintaxe:

```
<h3> <%= editable @article, :title %> </h3>
<p>  <%= editable @article, :content" %> </p>
```

the github link is just updated with this sample working, for those who want to check it:

https://github.com/diogowernik/x_editable_rails_demo